# css print - large table - last row getting split for some pages

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-7, page-break

I am using the following css to show a large amount of table data while printing.

```css
#toolbar.fixed + .content{
  overflow: visible;
  position: static;
  bottom: 0em;
}

table { page-break-after:auto }
  tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  thead { display:table-header-group }
  tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
```

The browser I am using is IE 7. The problem I am facing is that the data on the last row of some of the pages is getting split between the current page and the next page. I am trying to figure out if something is wrong with my css above or if I need to introduce additional css to prevent the last row of data (only on some pages) to stop getting split between two pages.

Answer (score 0):

`page-break-inside` is still unsupported in many major browsers:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp

Also note that page breaks are not permitted inside positioned objects.

Using `page-break-before: auto;` And `page-break-after: auto;` may fix this, but you can use [this page](http://www.westciv.com/style_master/academy/css_tutorial/advanced/printing.html) as a guide to create styles you need without using `page-break-inside` ...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.....
`function printControl(){

```
    var table = document.getElementById("DataList1");
    var count = table.rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if ((i % 4 == 0)&&(i!=0)) {
            table.rows[i].style.cssText = "page-break-after:always";
        }
    }
}`
```